# Filling GA4 dimensions retroactively based on page

Tags: google-analytics-4

Since the move to GA4 we've been sending the custom dimensions data like that, instead of defining the dimension names in custom_map and setting the values separately:

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXX', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension1': '$val1', 'dimension2': '$val2', 'dimension3': '$val3'}
});
```

Now we understood that the following code should be used instead:

```
gtag('config', 'G-XXXX', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'name1', 'dimension2': 'name2', 'dimension3': 'name3'},
  'name1': '$val1',
  'name2': '$val2',
  'name3': '$val3'
});
```

We also have the language and module in the page url that were sent alongside the page views.
Is the data from that period of time lost? Is there a way to fill the dimensions in retroactively based on the event page urls, or based on the data sent with the previous code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the values of your dimensions dynamically? or your wanna create dimensions in a dynamic mode? creating a new dimension requires 48 to get effected, and it is easy to create it by logging in your https://analytics.google.com/  account (you need to have at least Editor Role), then go to configure => create custom definitions and then create new dimension. then you should wait for  24/48 hours. remember once you created a dimension you cannot delete it and the User Property/Parameter value should be written with the exact spelling  you use in JS.

Comment: Not what the question meant. Clearly wrote 'retroactively'. Thanks